# Creating large number of directories, subdirectories and files

Tags: linux, windows, ntfs, ext3

Is there any tool or script available that creates millions of files directories, sub-directories and sub-sub-directories randomly in Linux and Windows.

Comment: Create a script, based on `touch` for a file and `mkdir` for a directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p folder{1..100000}/folder{1..100000}folder{1..100000}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kamèl , Dominique, for your the clue

I could able to achieve what I wanted.

Following example creates and copies files in 4 x 4 x 4 x 4 x 4 = 1024 directories

On Linux Host:

```
# ls -l
total 440
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:48 file1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:48 file2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:48 file3
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:48 file4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:49 file5
#

while read i ; do echo Creating directories - $i; mkdir -p $i ;  done <<< "`echo folder{1..4}/folder{1..4}/folder{1..4}/folder{1..4}/folder{1..4} | sed 's/ /\n/g'`"
while read i ; do echo Copying files at $i; cp file1 $i; done <<< "`echo folder{1..4} | sed 's/ /\n/g'`"      
while read i ; do echo Copying files at $i; cp file2 $i; done <<< "`echo folder{1..4}/folder{1..4} | sed 's/ /\n/g'`"
while read i ; do echo Copying files at $i; cp file3 $i; done <<< "`echo folder{1..4}/folder{1..4}/folder{1..4} | sed 's/ /\n/g'`"
while read i ; do echo Copying files at $i; cp file4 $i; done <<< "`echo folder{1..4}/folder{1..4}/folder{1..4}/folder{1..4} | sed 's/ /\n/g'`"
while read i ; do echo Copying files at $i; cp file5 $i; done <<< "`echo folder{1..4}/folder{1..4}/folder{1..4}/folder{1..4}/folder{1..4} | sed 's/ /\n/g'`"
# 
#
[root@DV-S563 tmp]# ls -lR | head -40
.:
total 456
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:48 file1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:48 file2
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:48 file3
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:48 file4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:49 file5
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder1
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder2
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder3
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder4

./folder1:
total 104
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:54 file1
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder1
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder2
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder3
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder4

./folder1/folder1:
total 104
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:54 file2
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder1
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder2
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder3
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder4

./folder1/folder1/folder1:
total 104
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:54 file3
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder1
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder2
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder3
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder4

./folder1/folder1/folder1/folder1:
total 104
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 86400 Nov  4 07:54 file4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 Nov  4 07:54 folder1
[root@DV-S563 tmp]#
```

On Windows Host:

```
PS C:\Temp> dir


    Directory: C:\Temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         6/19/2022   9:43 AM           2423 file1
-a----         6/19/2022   9:43 AM           2423 file2
-a----         6/19/2022   9:43 AM           2423 file3
-a----         6/19/2022   9:43 AM           2423 file4
-a----         6/19/2022   9:43 AM           2423 file5


PS C:\Temp> 

New-Item -Type Directory -Force -Path (1..4 -replace '^', 'folder').ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" }).ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" }).ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" }).ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" })
(1..4 -replace '^', 'folder') | % { Copy-Item file1 -destination $_ }
(1..4 -replace '^', 'folder').ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" }) | % { Copy-Item file2 -destination $_ }
(1..4 -replace '^', 'folder').ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" }).ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" }) | % { Copy-Item file3 -destination $_ }
(1..4 -replace '^', 'folder').ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" }).ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" }).ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" }) | % { Copy-Item file4 -destination $_ }
(1..4 -replace '^', 'folder').ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" }).ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" }).ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" }).ForEach({ 1..4 -replace '^', "$_\folder" }) | % { Copy-Item file5 -destination $_ }

PS C:\Temp> Get-ChildItem -Recurse


    Directory: C:\Temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder1
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder2
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder3
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder4
-a----         6/19/2022   9:43 AM           2423 file1
-a----         6/19/2022   9:43 AM           2423 file2
-a----         6/19/2022   9:43 AM           2423 file3
-a----         6/19/2022   9:43 AM           2423 file4
-a----         6/19/2022   9:43 AM           2423 file5


    Directory: C:\Temp\folder1


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder1
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder2
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder3
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder4
-a----         6/19/2022   9:43 AM           2423 file1


    Directory: C:\Temp\folder1\folder1


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder1
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder2
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder3
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder4
-a----         6/19/2022   9:43 AM           2423 file2


    Directory: C:\Temp\folder1\folder1\folder1


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder1
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder2
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder3
d-----         11/4/2022   8:30 PM                folder4
-a----         6/19/2022   9:43 AM           2423 file3
```